# How to handle large collection aggregations after grouping?

Tags: mongodb, .net-core, nosql, bigdata

My collection is storing every click in our system, a click document looks something like (simplified) -

```cs
        [BsonId]
        [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
        public string _id { get; set; }
        public string VisitorGuid { get; set; }
        public int AccountId { get; set; }
```

So `_id` is the auto-generated unique identifer of each click.
`VisitorGuid` is a generated guid for every unique customer (Cookie based) so if a customer clicks a link twice, it will create 2 documents with different `_id` but the same `VisitorGuid`.

My Actual question - 
On this collection I'm doing statistics, so using the example above I generate a report of how many visitors and how many clicks each account had.
To achieve that my query has 2 group stages, the first one groups by `VisitorGuid`, and projects a new document that hold the clicks amount for the specific `VisitorGuid`, that way at the end I know how many clicks I have in total (summing the visitors clicks) and also how many visitors I had. (IRL I group by multiple fields not only the accountId)

My problem is that after the first group-by Mongo can't utilize the indexes, and that query can take up to several seconds depends on the date range I filter by. The collection currently holds around 5m documents, what mostly scares me is that it needs be able to hold way more and I'm not sure how will It handle such query then.

Query example:

```cs
            // Use the dates to create ObjectId type for comparison
            var startId = new ObjectId(request.FromDate.UtcDateTime, 0, 0, 0).ToString();
            var endId = new ObjectId(request.ToDate.UtcDateTime, 0, 0, 0).ToString();

            //filter
            var builder = Builders<Click>.Filter;
            var clickFilters = builder.Gte(c => c._id, startId)
                & builder.Lte(c => c._id, endId);

            var aggregateOptions = new AggregateOptions { AllowDiskUse = true };
            //aggregate clicks -
            var clicksAggregationTask = Task.Run(() => collection.Aggregate(aggregateOptions)
                .Match(clickFilters)
                //group into visitors
                .Group(c => c.VisitorGuid, g => new Result()
                {
                    AccountId = g.First().AccountId,
                    ClickCount = g.Count()
                })
                //statistics
                .Group(
                c => new GroupByResult()
                {
                    AccountId = c.AccountId,
                },
                g => new Res()
                {
                    AccountId = g.First().AccountId,
                    ClickCount = g.Sum(group => group.ClickCount),
                    VisitorCount = g.Count()
                })
                .ToListAsync());
```

Answer (score 0):

Indexes apply when the data is known ahead of query time (the indexes need to be built from the data). When the data is produced in an aggregation query it won't be using indexes in the "collection index" sense of the word. That said, certain in-memory operations can in principle utilize algorithms like [hash joins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_join) (I don't know specifically how this applies to MongoDB) which can be thought of as a different sense of "index".

With the aggregation pipeline, the idea I would say in general is to stream data from one stage to the next as much as possible. So at some point scale-wise you may need to adjust your queries to have this streaming.

You can test performance or a larger data set simply by creating such a larger data set.